# Nodal analysis; am I doing it correctly?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here is the circuit:

[image]

In the following, switch S has been open for long. No initial energy.

- C = 10 uF.
- R0 = 24 Ω
- R1 = 12 Ω
- R2 =
  18 Ω
- R3 = 6 Ω
- Power Pr3 dissipated in R3 is 24 watts.

  1. What are the powers dissipated Pr2 and Pr1 in R2 and R1 resistances?
  2. What are the nodal voltages V3 and V2?

Here is my attempt:

I started by using R3 power dissipation of 24 watts and solving for current by sqrt(24/6)= 2 A

Then, multiply 2 A * 6 ohms= 12 V so V3 = 12.

Nodal analysis: all loops going clockwise

```
Loop 1: V1- V1/24 - (12-V2)/12 =0
Loop 2: V2- (V2-12)/18- 12/6 +V2/12
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Your V<sub>3</sub> and I<sub>3</sub> calculations are correct. Since you now have I<sub>3</sub> and you know R<sub>2</sub> is 18 Ω you can easily calculate V<sub>2</sub>.

With those results you have all you need to calculate the powers.

Comment: So v2=(v2-v3)/18   then (v2-12)/18=12 volts. If this is right the v1 will be v1=R0*V2

Comment: I don't follow your logic in the first sentence of your comment. Check it again. In any case since R2 = 18 Ω and I3 = 2 A you know the voltage drop across R2 and can add this to V3 to get V2.